# Remove orphaned files that were created based on a "parent" file

Tags: powershell

I use an application that converts my scanned documents into .pdf format and then constantly monitors folders and subfolders but instead of converting every pdf into searchable pdfs, I have it set up to create a .txt file with an identical name so I can use the contents of these text files as a reference in my other powershell scripts to name and manipulate my pdfs based on their content but when changes are made to the filenames of any pdfs, new .txt files are created based on the new name and the old ones remain.

I need to search a directory and subfolders for .txt files that do not have a matching .pdf and delete them.

I have tried variations of the following to find said files.

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -File |
Group-Object -Property Directory,BaseName |
Where-Object Count -gt 0 |
Select-Object Name
```

and

```
Push-Location $source

#does not work with recurse on only works on files in current folder.

Get-childitem -recurse *.txt | ForEach {     
    if (!(test-path "$($_.BaseName).pdf")){           
      "$($_.BaseName).pdf missing"
    }
  } 

Pop-Location
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do what you want, you need to be more explicit in the type of files you want Get-ChildItem to retrieve.
Next, make sure you combine the file's FullName with a .pdf extension in order to check if the .txt and matching .pdf files are in the same subfolder.
The `BaseName` property is not enough for that because you need to match the DirectoryName as well.

Here's two options for you:

**Using a loop and `Test-Path`:**

```
# collect only the FullName properties of .txt files
(Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\Test' -File -Recurse -Filter '*.txt').FullName |  
ForEach-Object {
    # test if there is a .pdf file with the same path and filename
    $pdfToLookFor = [System.IO.Path]::ChangeExtension($_, '.pdf')
    # if there is no matching .pdf file, remove the .txt file
    if (!(Test-Path -Path $pdfToLookFor)) {
        Remove-Item -Path $_ -WhatIf
    }
}
```

**Using `Group-Object` on the full path and file name WITHOUT the extension:**

```
$orphans = Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\Test' -File -Recurse -Include '*.pdf', '*.txt' | 
Group-Object {$_.FullName -replace '\.(pdf|txt)$'} |                      # group on the FullName without extension
Where-Object {$_.Count -eq 1 -and $_.Group[0].Extension -eq '.txt'}       # filter out all except orphaned .txt files
# next loop over the groups of orphan files and delete them
$orphans | ForEach-Object { 
    Remove-Item -Path $_.Group[0] -WhatIf                                 # remove the orphan files
}
```

<sup>In both examples I have added safety switch `-WhatIf` to the `Remove-Item` command.

That way nothing gets deleted but instead in the editor you can see what files *would be* removed.

Once you have convinced yourself the output is correct, take away the `-WhatIf` switch and run the code again</sup>

Comment: Thank you, both work perfectly and I can see how I was going about it the wrong way now.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: improved as suggested by @Theo

This also works

```
# Get all files
$FileList = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -File

# Extract all PDFs full paths filtering by extension and remove the extension
$PdfList = $FileList.where({ $_.Extension -eq '.pdf' }).foreach({ Join-Path -Path $_.DirectoryName -ChildPath $_.BaseName }) 

# Filter all files by TXT 
# Then pipe to remove only those not having the same directory and name(except the extension) as any in the $PdfList
$FileList.where({ $_.Extension -eq '.txt' }).where({
        (Join-Path -Path $_.DirectoryName -ChildPath $_.BaseName) -notin $PdfList
    }) | Remove-Item
```

Comment: Better join the basename with `$_.DirectoryName`, not the (object) `$_.Directory`